how to run alloydb auth proxy in background in a pipeline?
I want to start alloydb auth proxy in one of the steps in my pipeline. I'm using bash. The problem is that the proxy starts but then it never pass to the next step.
When I was using cloud sql proxy, I use the following command to run the proxy in the background:
./cloud-sql-proxy $(instance_connection_name)  --address IPADDRESS --port 5432 --impersonate-service-account $(iac_deployer_email) &>/dev/null&
But it seems this don't work for alloydb auth proxy. How can I escape and run the proxy in backuground so in next step in my pipeline I can connect using psql??
This is how my azure pipeline looks:

Thanks.

In pipeline, each Bash task will have a separate session to run the commands/scripts set on the task. When the task is completed, the session normally will be closed. Some processes started by the task (or by the commands run on the task) also could be stopped.
For your case, you can try to add the dependent/associated command lines to one Bash task, instead of separating them to multiple tasks. By this way, all the associated command lines can be executed within the same session.
